# Possible to add a condition for linked table fields in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

Can someone suggest me a solution to add condition for reference table items in linq.

I have a master table called TourPackage, which include

```
public class TourPackage{
   public int TourID { get; set; }
   public string TourName { get; set; }
   public List<IncludedItems> IncludedItems { get; set; }
}
```

Every tour package contain some selected items reference like

```
public class IncludedItems {
   public int TourID { get; set; }
   public int IncludedID { get; set; }
   public Included Included { get; set; }
}
```

All included item should have a reference to Included  table for lookup reference

```
public class Included {
   public int IncludedID { get; set; }
   public string IncludedValue { get; set; }
}
```

now i have set of IncludedID like [1,2,3], Is it possible to filter TourPackage based on IncludedID.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using something like:

```
var myIds = new List<int> {123,456};
var result = context.TourPackages
    .Where(x => x.IncludedItems.Any(a => a.Included !=null && myIds.Contains(a.Included.IncludedId)))
    .ToList();
```

You might have to include some relations manually depending if you're lazy loading is setup or not.

More info at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the option. I can't try like this 'x => x.Included.IncludedId == 123'. because i have a big list IncludedId to compire. not like 123, its an array [123,456,789,455]

Answer (score 1):

You can use following code

> I have sample array(i.e `example`) which contains ID's we check if current Id(i.e `ele.Included.IncludedID`) is present in the array of id's.

```
listex.Where(x => x.IncludedItems.Any(ele => example.Contains(ele.Included.IncludedID))).ToList();
```

sample:-

```
int[] example = new int[3];
example[0] = 123;
example[1] = 456;
example[2] = 789;

List<TourPackage> listex = new List<TourPackage>();
List<TourPackage> filterList = listex.Where(x => x.IncludedItems.Any(ele => example.Contains(ele.Included.IncludedID))).ToList();
```